# How to align an equation reference (1) to the right

Tags: cross-referencing, equations

I have a centred equation and I'd like to place a (1) on the same line as the equation, but aligned to the right, so that I can refer back to the equation in future. What I have at the moment is:

```
\center  $ \begin{pmatrix} e & \frac{f}{2} \\ \frac{f}{5} & g \end{pmatrix} = L^T %
  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} L $ \flushright' (1)
```

Comment: I recommend reading chapter 3 of [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align} \label{foo}
\begin{pmatrix} e & \frac{f}{2} \\ \frac{f}{5} & g \end{pmatrix} 
  &= L^T   \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} L 
\end{align}

See Eqn~\ref{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `align` instead of `equation`?

Comment: why not? and it is not a good idea when you change my code in a way that it did not work!

Comment: `align` gives different spacing than `equation` and the latter is surely preferable for single line equations. Of course the `&` before the `=` serves no purpose in a single line equation. I believe that simplicity is better.

Comment: sure, if I want the spacing of equation then I'd used it ...

Answer (score 8):

What is wrong with

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\begin{pmatrix} e & \frac{f}{2} 
 \\ 
 \frac{f}{5} & g 
\end{pmatrix} 
= L^T 
\begin{pmatrix} 
 a & b 
\\ 
 c & d 
\end{pmatrix} 
L 
\end{equation}
```

then use `\eqref{eq:1}` (assuming `amsmath`)